# Como Identificar caracteres

Tags: java, android, edittext, caracteres

Tenho uma *class* que pega uma `String` e olha o primeiro caractere e caso o caractere for vazio (" ") ele me retorna a primeira letra.

```
public String textReturn(String x){
   int v1 = 0,v2 = 1;
   String a =" ";

   while(true){

      if( x.substring(v1,v2).equal(" ")){

         a =  x.substring(v1,v2);
         break;
      }else{
         v1++;
         v2++;
      }
   }

  return a;
}
```

Porém esse texto vem de uma *EditText* e se nela eu der um enter conta como se fosse um caractere, queria saber como faço para conseguir pular o quebra de linha ou se ele também e um caractere tipo *String a.equal(b/)*

Comment: Normalmente compnonentes EditText possuem uma propriedade "text" que já te retorna o texto sem caracteres especiais. Poderia usar algo como: textReturn( editText.text). Mas sua pergunta não está muito clara posso não ter entendido o real problema

Comment: esse meu método pega um text qualquer e verifica se o primeiro caractere e vazio ('" "), se for vazio ele olha o segundo senão ele me retorna o caractere... isso funciona, mas se eu der um ente ele quebra a linha e quando ele olha o primeiro caractere não vai ta vazio pois ele considera o quebra de linha um caractere... queria saber qual e o simbolo do quebra de linha pra comparar ou como pular o quebra de linha e ir para o caractere seguinte.

Comment: Como você passa o texto do Edit pra ele? Não entendi como o "Enter" esta indo dentro da string, não esta pegando o texto "puro" do Edit?

Comment: eu chamo o método textReturn(edittext.getText) e logo em seguida meu método verifica os caracteres. mas se no EditText eu apertar o Enter ele considera a quebra de linha um caractere

Comment: tipo assim o método olha os caractere e pula os caracteres vazio e me mostra na tela a primeira letra, usando Toast, .. isso dar certo , posso dar quantos espaço quiser que ele pula os espaços e me retorna a primeira letra, mas quando aperto o Enter ele me retorna no Toast vazio

Answer (score 0):

Por que não utilizar o método "TrimStart(new char[] { ' ', '\n' })" e validar se a string retornada é igual a original, caso não seja retornar a primeira letra? Se o que você quer é retornar a primeira letra quando ele acha o espaço está retornando o espaço e também, do modo como está o método, se não houver um espaço no início do texto ocorre loop infinito, e se as variavéis V1 e V2 são sempre iguais por não utilizar só uma?

Comment: as variavéis são diferentes e isso estar dentro de um try catch se der loop não trava

Comment: eu so queria que do mesmo jeito que olha se o caractere e vazio também queria que olhasse se era uma quebra de linha

Comment: \n = quebra de linha